# Is it possible to configure PassportJS strategies on the requests?

Tags: passport.js

I'm building a multitenant application that manages requests for various different domains and each domain will have it's own set of authentications configured, so, for example, there would be several Facebook API ID and Secret pairs and not all know at start time.

Is there a way, with PassportJS, to configure the strategy on the fly on each request?

Comment: I assume all possible domains are pre-defined known at  start time. I think, rather than configuring dynamic strategies on each request, you would have to instantiate all possible authenticator (`new Passport()`) and configure express to use different authenticator according to specific domain

Comment: No, they aren't. They are defined on the database. It's a multi-tenant application where customers come, sign up, add their domain, their twitter id and key, facebook id and key, etc.

Comment: I know the question targets specifically PassportJS, but have you considered [grant](https://github.com/simov/grant)? It is a single config middleware, so it should be easier to configure it dynamically. Also PassportJS is not actively maintained anymore.

Comment: @thammada.ts: thank you. I'm not against not using PassportJS. I'll check out grant. How do you know it's not maintained anymore?

Comment: You can check the github issues and commit history. It might be because the it's already full featured. But personally I like the `grant` approach more